# Docker-compose up works very slow

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a web app with Django (and angular as compiled app) and I'm trying to run it using docker containers. 
Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
    version: '3'
    services:
    web:
      build: ./
      command: bash -c "python manage.py migrate && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput &&  gunicorn decoderservice.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000"
      ports:
        - "8000:8000"
      env_file:
        - ./.env.dev
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7
WORKDIR /orionprotocolservice/
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
COPY ./requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /orionprotocolservice/
```

Program works, but performance is extremely slow (about 17s for loading the main page). Routing between pages are also slow. Interestingly, if I click to some button twice, it immediately loads. 
What is happening, who could help?

Comment: From my experience, this could be a number of things, including the operating system you're running Docker on. If it happens to be mac, I might have an answer for you :D What's your OS?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am running it on Windows 10.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't dig anything to solve your issue within short research time I had. Seems like it's not the problem of your container (eg. you're not mounting any external volumes), neither it's a network stack problem (you basically run just gunicorn). You could try disabling hyperv and see what happens (`dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V` in your powershell). I can't bet it would work, though. I'd rather suggest a typical solution: "if your bathroom door is stuck, burn down your house". I.e. moving to linux would work perfectly :D

Comment: @AlexKarshin What would be your answer for Mac?

Comment: @AlexKarshin have you solved this ?

Comment: @SandeshSapkota no I haven't and I'm not even looking for a solution. This question is two years old now and therefore it's outdated. Docker tools for mac and win made a giant leap since. So I encourage you to do your own research and find your own solution. If you do find it, feel free to post it here. Me, I'm happy with my linux and I do not focus on other operating systems. Good luck 